# Retrieve apt-get package in differing distros

Tags: apt, raspbian

I have **ROS Indigo** installed in *Ubuntu 14.04* on a macbook pro. I can find and install the package `ros-indigo-openni-launch`.

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-openni-launch
[sudo] password for jackson: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ros-indigo-openni-launch is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 40 not upgraded.
```

I also have **ROS Indigo** installed in *Raspbian "Jessie" 4.1.19* on Raspberry Pi 2 model B. If I try to install `ros-indigo-openni-launch` I get

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-openni-launch
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-openni-launch
```

How can I install this package onto raspbian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no `ros-indigo-openni-launch` in Ubuntu, see [package search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ros-indigo-openni-launch&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all). Therefore I would assume that you have installed a new package repository on your laptop.

You can do the same thing on the RPi with Debian. I think the [Ubuntu ARM instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/UbuntuARM) should mostly work.

As an alternative you could consider installing Ubuntu on your Raspberry Pi 2 and have the same distribution on both systems. This usually makes configuration easier.